# c preprocessor dereference array

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I do not think it is possible but i am asking in case it is just because i lack imagination. Can i dereference a static array (like a constant string) from a macro. For instance:

```
#define SECOND(a,b,...) b
#define IS_PROBE(...) SECOND(__VA_ARGS__, 0)
#define PROBE() ~,1
#define NOT(x) IS_PROBE(NOT_##x)
#define NOT_0 PROBE()
#define TESTLEN(s,i) NOT(s[i])
```

Which would allow to test length of a string for instance TESTLEN("toto",4) would evaluate to 1 but anything else then 4 as second argument and it would evaluate to 0

So is there a way to dereference an array from C preprocessor ?

Note that example above is pointless, i do not care about array size (yes i know about sizeof and all). I want to do arithmetic on characters in a constant string (index into an array and do c preprocessor arithmetic with each character) from c preprocessor if at all possible.

Comment: Only trial will tell you what your (pre-)compiler allows you to do that. You would be better off using C code, instead of pre-processor VOODOO.

Comment: Simply try it: With GCC use the option `-E` to see what the preprocessor produces.

Answer (score 2):

> So is there a way to dereference an array from C preprocessor ?

No. C preprocesssor knows nothing about any arrays.

> I want to do arithmetic on characters in a constant string

You can't do anything in preprocessor with a constant string. You could *generate code* that does something with a constant string:

```
#define STRLEN(s)  (\
    !s[0]?0: \
    !s[1]?1: \
    !s[2]?2: \
    !s[3]?3: \
    !s[4]?4: \
    -1)
static const int len = STRLEN("abc"); // gcc extension
static const int arr[STRLEN("abc")]; // error
_Static_assert(STRLEN("abc") == 3); // error
```

The `STRLEN` expands to code that is evaluated on compiling stage. But note that it is a gcc *extension* that in static variable initialization it is possible to use a string literal. `STRLEN` is *not* a constant expression and can't be used as such.